# Can not start Secure ZooKeeper

Tags: kerberos, apache-zookeeper

I installed Kerberos for CDH 5.3.2 following this [official document](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-3-x/topics/cm_sg_authentication.html).

Also I followed [ZooKeeper Authentication](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-3-x/topics/cdh_sg_zookeeper_security.html#topic_11_unique_2) to configure a secure ZooKeeper, where I did the following :
1). created principals for each ZK server and exported their keytab files; 
2). configured related files, like `zoo.cfg`,`jaas.conf` and `java.env`;

But when I tried to start ZK Cluster it failed. I checked the log files and it reported the following exceptions:

> 2015-09-22 15:19:08,232 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain: Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
>   java.io.IOException: Could not configure server because SASL configuration did not allow the  ZooKeeper server to authenticate itself properly: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: 
>   Checksum failed
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory.configureSaslLogin(ServerCnxnFactory.java:207)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:87)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:135)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)

**Check sum failed**. I've no idea what that means.

I'm sure my Kerberized CDH is running OK because I can access HDFS and submit YARN job as corresponding principals. Besides, I can get ticket for zookeeper's principals by the command `kinit -k -t <path-to-keytab> <zookeeper/FQDN@REALM>`.

So what caused the problem? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: A must-read for any mortal that dares invoke Kerberos foul spirits: **_Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate_** (by the guy who actually maintains the Hadoop / ZK / Spark code base) e.g. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html

Comment: Also https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/terrors.html for the section about "ZooKeeper birthday present" that may be helpful if your cluster fails in exactly 365 days...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by regenerating zookeeper keytabs in kerberos administration over Cloddra Manager. I did this in 5.5.1 version of CDH.

I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Kerberos-Authentication-Wizard-failing-to-generate-workable/m-p/25748#M4011, Cloudera manager tries to use tcp but the KDC by default is configured to work with udp only! For reference: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/kdc_conf.html

To resolve: in your kdc.conf add `kdc_tcp_ports = 88` below `kdc_ports = ...` (88 is the default tcp port for kerberos) and restart the service: `service krb5-kdc restart`. Now manually start zookeeper and the rest of the services.